# what do the character combinations mean in SQL Report Writer drivers?

Tags: oracle, printing, report

I am looking at this SRW driver in Oracle EBS, and this line doesn't make sense:

```
    code "bold on"          esc "[1m"
```

1. Is this a custom code definition?
2. What is  **esc "[1m"** part? Is this some sort of a key combination?
3. Is this specific to Oracle/EBS or is this a bash thing?

If this question is not suitable to stackoverflow, please suggest the correct Stack Exchange Community

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've just found this page http://www.pclviewer.com/resources/pcl_symbolset.html. I think this is PCL symbol set.

Comment: Is this the java class?

Comment: This is not a Java class. It is  from SQL Report Writer file (something.prt) defined for Oracle EBS printing.